# Creating designs with nested loops in java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

As a part of my cs assignment, we have to create different designs in java using nested for loops.The one I'm having problems with is this we
 [image]
The goal of this assignment is to recreate the tree using nested for loops but the height of the tree can change based on users desired height. This is my code

```
int nline = 10;
int nstar = 1;
int nspace = nline - 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= nline; i++) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= nspace; y++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    for (int x = 1; x <= nstar; x++)
        System.out.print("\\|/ ");
    System.out.println();
    nstar++;
    nspace--;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    nspace = nline + 5;
    for (int x = 1; x <= nspace; x++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println("|||");
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
    nspace = nline + 4;
    for (int x = 1; x <= nspace; x++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println("_|||_");
}
```

My current output looks like this, how can I correct the code so the output appears as in the link above?

```
         \|/ 
        \|/ \|/ 
       \|/ \|/ \|/ 
      \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ 
     \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ 
    \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ 
   \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ 
  \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ 
 \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ 
\|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ 
               |||
               |||
              _|||_
```

Comment: "I'm having problems with is this" -- Can you be more precise in your description of the problem? Does the tree look funny? Did you get an exception? Did your keyboard catch on fire?

Comment: and your question is ?

Comment: "tree look funny" is not a good description either.

Comment: I think printing \|/ where only \ are required will not help much. Perhaps you start with that one.

Answer (score 2):

Not the complete answer, but some hints. To keep it simple let's take a look at the upper part of the tree only (your first for-loop)

The crux of this section is how the parts you have to print in every line depend on the height of the tree.

The approach you are following ( spaces and tree-part ) is not really dynamic, try splitting it up in all the parts which are needed ( spaces, leaves, trunk, even more leaves ):

So your first for-loop could look something like this:

```
int height = 10;

for (int line = 0; line < height ; line++ ){

   // print the spaces needed for this line
   int spaces = ...
   for ( int x = 0 ; x < spaces ; x++){
       System.out.print(" ");
   }

   // print the leaves left of the trunk
   int leafes_l = ...
   for ( int x = 0 ; x < leafes_l ; x++){
       System.out.print("\\");
   }

    // print the trunk
    System.out.print("|");

    // print the leaves right of the trunk  
    int leafes_r = ...
    for ( int x = 0 ; x < leafes_r ; x++){
       System.out.print("/");
    }
 
    System.out.println("");

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is something that should work. This assumes that the trunk is 3 wide. You can obviously wrap the single line System.out.print("...") in a single iteration for loop if you really must present only for loops.

```
public static void printTree(int leavesHeight, int trunkHeight) {

    /* Print Trunk & Leaves */
    for (int i = 0; i < leavesHeight; i++) {
        int lineLength = (2 * i + 1);

        /* Print Spaces */
        for (int j = 0; j < leavesHeight - 1 - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        /* Print Left Leaves */
        for (int j = 1; j <= lineLength / 2; j++) {
            System.out.print("\\");
        }

        /* Print Trunk */
        System.out.print("|");

        /* Print Right Leaves */
        for (int j = ((lineLength / 2) + 1); j < lineLength; j++) {
            System.out.print("/");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    /* Print Trunk */
    for (int i = 0; i < trunkHeight - 1; i++) {

        /* Print Spaces */
        for (int j = 0; j < (leavesHeight - 2); j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    /* Print Spaces */
    for (int j = 0; j < (leavesHeight - 3); j++) {
         System.out.print(" ");
    }

    /* Print Bottom Trunk */
    System.out.print("_|||_");

}
```